# Samsung S3 i9300 rooted with Heimdall.  Am I able to unroot with ODIN?

Tags: unrooting, odin, heimdall

I rooted my phone with the [Samsung Galaxy S III: Full Update Guide](http://wiki.cyanogenmod.com/wiki/Samsung_Galaxy_S_III%3a_Full_Update_Guide)

I stumbled when I tried to flash the CyanogenMod.  I do not get the install from zip file command while in the ClockworkMod recovery mode. So I can't seem to be able to find the zip file to install the CyanogenMod.

What I am trying to do now is to unroot my S3, but seeing that I rooted it using Heimdall rather than ODIN, is it still safe to unroot using ODIN?

Comment: Place the .zip on the internal sdcard, the try again with no ext. Sd card inserted

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I did not have any SD card inserted while attempting the flashing

Comment: Oh, mixed that up... Do you really have the cwm running. Just wondering bec. there's a stock recovery that misses this feature.

Comment: you're right, when i do the vol up + home + power button combo, it takes me to android recovery which i had thought was the CWM recovery all long. Does this mean i do not have CWM recovery on my phone at all? Though my phone status says it has been modified

Comment: What if you don't do the combo and boot regularly? The normal boot img has been replaced I think.

Comment: My stock OS is still booting. But whatever has changed, i duno other than the phone status.

Comment: will there be any issues if i were to continue to install cf-root with ODIN with my phone in its current state? Or if i were to unroot with ODIN? I can't seem to find any unrooting guides with heimdall.

Comment: CF-root should be Ok in advance. You can also check http://xray.io/dl It checks for rootibility via common exploits just to see if you could get away with the newest super1click to root. Odin/heimdall use both the same Samsung proprietary download mode to flash images. Odin is Samsung Software while heimdall is open source and runs in Win/Mac/Linux. I have used the latter so far w/o problems.

Comment: thanks for the tips, i have managed to flash cyanogenmod after installing cf root!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't "unroot" per se with Odin; you just flash a stock, unrooted ROM that wipes out everything currently on the phone.  It shouldn't matter whether you use Odin or Heimdall.

Note also that unrooting won't matter if you've flashed anything with Odin, since that also voids your warranty and is recorded on the device.